# Permanently enable plain text mode in Yahoo! Mail

Tags: yahoo-mail, formatting, text

The last button (icon) in the image below is *Switch to Plain Text* mode. It fits perfectly with my needs.

[image: Yahoo Mail compose window]

How can I permanently switch to plain text mode?

(If there is no such feature, I guess I will create a custom script and post it here.)

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Mail's "Basic Mail" mode can *only* send plaintext email, so using it is a heavy-handed way to permanently switch to plain text mode.  You can enable Basic Mail by clicking on:

Settings -> More Settings -> Switch to basic Mail

If you like sending low-frills non-HTML email, the rest of what comes with Basic Mail may also work for you.

Getting out of Basic Mail only takes one click: "switch to the newest Yahoo Mail".